# validates_associated and HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-and-belongs-to-many

Article HABTM authors

In Article model, i say:

```
validates_associated :authors
```

But, by creating of the new Article, this validation does't happen, because i don't see the errors.

Another errors are displayed properly, but this.

I render errors so:

```
<div class="errors">
    <%= article_form.error_messages %>
</div>
```

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validates_associated should work with any kind of association.
Try to display your errors either with:

```
<%= @article.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
```

or

```
<%- for author in @article.authors %>
  <%= author.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
<%- end %>
```